# northmost latitude

Tags: trigonometry, celestial-mechanics

From the book *Astronomy, principles and practice.* I cannot solve the second part.

Assuming the Earth to be a sphere of radius 6378 km calculate the great circle distance in kilometers between
London (51◦ 30 N, 0◦) and New York (40◦ 45 N, 74◦ W).
Find also the most northerly latitude reached on the great circle arc.

the great circle distance is given by

$\Delta\sigma=\arccos(\sin51.5\sin40.75 + \cos51.5 \cos40.75\cos74)$

Then I converted the result to radians and used  $d=r\Delta\sigma$ to get 5786km. Then I tried to use the departure equation but logically it does not seem to correspond to the problem.

Comment: i found the great circle distance.Then i tried to picture a spherical triangle but i coudnt.Then i realized that the max altitude is reached halfway the arc.Stil can't find a solvable triangle

Comment: Great! If you include that (including the calculations) there will be a *much* greater chance that your question will be answered. Showing what you've done also tells people something about your level and where you might have gone wrong, and if they know these things, the answers will surely be better. Also, I am the one who downvoted your question, but if you edit it to include your try I will upvote it. Cheers

Comment: ok shall i do it at the comments?

Comment: No, you can edit your question (just below it).

Comment: i wrote down the eq

Comment: Did the book show you a formula something like $\sin(course_1) \cos(lat_1)=\sin(course_2) \cos(lat_2)$?

Comment: no it didn't.The book only shows 4 basic eq (cos,sine,4parts formula and analogue of cos formula)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the formulas you can use are the ones on this page:
http://www.diracdelta.co.uk/science/source/s/p/spherical%20triangles/source.html
(except for the area formula, which is not of any use here anyway).

Label the following points on the sphere: $A$ at London,
$B$ at New York, $C$ at the north pole.
Labeling the opposite sides of the spherical triangle $a$, $b$, $c$,
assuming those are all angular measurements in radians,
then $A$ (London) is $b$ radians from $C$ (the north pole)
so the latitude of London is $lat_A = \frac\pi2 - b$;
so $\sin(lat_A) = \cos b$ and $\cos(lat_A) = \sin b$.
We can see then that the great circle formula is just one of the cosine formulas, which you correctly applied.

Once you have the distance $c$ from $A$ to $B$, it is relatively
quick and easy to get the departure angles at New York and London by
applying the sine law to $\triangle ABC$:
$$
\frac{\sin A}{\sin a} = \frac{\sin B}{\sin b} = \frac{\sin C}{\sin c}.
$$
Keep this in mind about the sine law: it's not one big equation, it's actually
three equations, $\frac{\sin A}{\sin a} = \frac{\sin B}{\sin b}$,
$\frac{\sin A}{\sin a} = \frac{\sin C}{\sin c}$,
and $\frac{\sin B}{\sin b} = \frac{\sin C}{\sin c}$.
We usually use only one of the three equations at a time.

You already know $a$, $b$, $C$, and $c$, so you can get $A$ from
$\frac{\sin A}{\sin a} = \frac{\sin C}{\sin c}$ (one equation, one unknown)
and $B$ from $\frac{\sin B}{\sin b} = \frac{\sin C}{\sin c}$.

Either angle $A$ or angle $B$ can help you find the maximum latitude of the great circle, but just one of them will be enough. Suppose we just figured out the angle at $A$.
The trick then is to draw a new spherical triangle with vertices at $A$
and $C$, with the third vertex somewhere along the great-circle path from 
$A$ to $B$.  Possible choices for the third vertex are the point
where the great circle crosses the equator, or the point of maximum latitude
itself.

Call the new vertex $B'$ and let $a'$ be the length of the arc 
from $B'$ to $C$. The side of $\triangle AB'C$ opposite $B'$ is still
$b$ (the arc from $A$ to $C$ has not changed),
and the side opposite $A$ is $a'$. The angle at $A$ also either has not
changed, or it's $\frac\pi2$ minus the old angle; either way, its sine
is still $\sin A$. So the sine law applied to $\triangle AB'C$ says that
$$
\frac{\sin A}{\sin a'} = \frac{\sin B'}{\sin b}.
$$

If you chose to put $B'$ at the maximum latitude, the angle of 
$\triangle AB'C$ at $B'$ must be a right angle; so you have three knowns
($\sin A$, $B'$, and $b$) and one unknown $a'$ to solve for.
Then the latitude of $B'$ is $\frac\pi2 - a'$.

If you chose to put $B'$ at the crossing of the great circle and the equator,
the arc $a'$ is $\frac\pi2$ (the arc from the equator to the pole);
so you have three knowns ($\sin A$, $a'$, and $b$) and one unknown $B'$ to solve for.
Then $\frac\pi2 - B'$ is the angle at which the great circle crosses
the equator, which is also the maximum latitude on the great circle.

Comment: Thank you but i still don't get the part after the angle calculation.My spherical trig knowledge is really basic.Can you be more specific about the calculations of max alt?

Comment: Could you please explain why B' must be a right angle?

Comment: @ArnabChowdhury "If you chose to put $B'$ at the maximum latitude, the angle of 
$\triangle AB'C$ at $B'$ must be a right angle" because if it is **not** a right angle, then as you travel along the great circle at that point you are either getting closer to the pole (so the maximum latitude is still in front of you) or you are getting farther from the pole (so the maximum latitude is behind you).